# grey goo planet which assimilates tech and spreads through the galaxy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, nanotechnology

I read this short story a while back about this grey goo planet, figured one of you might have happened upon it.

- starts off with a space fleet investigating a planet
- grey, completely spherical, uniform to the core in its composition
- drones sent to surface disappear and are consumed
- captain of main craft realises it's the remnants of a nanite experiment gone awry
- self-replication took over entire planet without a kill switch
- planet obtains drone tech and with it, ballistic weapons and space travel
- proceeds to destroy fleet and send infection craft to other systems
- secondary craft has the last lightdrive in what remains of the fleet
- sends remaining crew and tech with it to warn the rest of the galaxy

Comment: One of these, possibly; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GreyGoo

Comment: In particular, the TV Tropes links to this story, which may fit the bill: http://qntm.org/gorge

Comment: @kundor Why not post that as a possible answer?

Answer (score 3):

Among the list of "grey goo" stories on TV Tropes, provided in the comments by Richard, is "Gorge" by Sam Hughes, which fits the description.
Here it is: http://qntm.org/gorge

Comment: Even if this turns out not to be the right story, it was still an excellent read. You have my +1